# textField allowing all characters despite ShouldChangeCharactersIn function

Tags: swift, text, uitextfield, character

As I'm trying to internalize code I've been using for years (without much understanding), I've created my version that *in theory* should copy its purpose.
I have a textField in which I'm only allowing decimal numbers and one period - ".". However, at the moment, my textField is allowing any character to be entered.

I have imported the UITextFieldDelegate class, connected my UITextField as an outlet, and set my textfield  to the textFieldDelefate in viewDidLoad.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn      range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

   //characterSet that holds digits
var allowed = CharacterSet.decimalDigits

//initialize the period for use as a characterSet
let period = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: ".")

//adding these two characterSets together
allowed.formUnion(period)

//all the characters not in the allowed union
let inverted = allowed.inverted

//if latest input is from the characters not allowed is present (aka, empty), do not change the characters in the text range
if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: inverted) != nil
{
    return false
}
    //if the text already contains a period and the string contains one as well, do not change output
else if (textField.text?.contains("."))! && string.contains(".")
{
    return false
}
//however, if not in the inverted set, allow the string to replace latest value in the text
else
{
    return true
}
```

This function is not disabling the more than one period and invert of decimal numbers.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working, seems to be working when i test it.

Comment: No way. decimal and period only?

Comment: Yep, numbers and a single period only. Did you try testing it in a simple project with just a view controller and a single text field?

Comment: shoot. As silly as it sounds (& if its not too much of a hassle), would you mind posting your code? I can't figure what I'm missing in mine.

Comment: To your last comment, yes. Exactly where I've been testing this but no luck.

Comment: I posted an answer, see if that helps, or if I'm missing something

Comment: It must have been an issue with my project. I created a new one (with your code to be safe) and it worked instantly. Thank you so much for the time, Dennis!

Comment: No worries, glad it worked for you. Feel free to delete this question if you don't think it adds value to `SO` (considering you answered your own question :) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems to work for me, I moved some of the character setup into some lazy vars so that it is only done once, and not every time the delegate is called.

```
import UIKit

class ContainerController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    //characterSet that holds digits
    lazy var allowed:CharacterSet = {
        var allowed = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
        //initialize the period for use as a characterSet
        let period = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: ".")
        //adding these two characterSets together
        allowed.formUnion(period)
        return allowed
    }()

    lazy var inverted:CharacterSet = {
        return allowed.inverted
    }()

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
    }


    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        print("shouldChangeCharactersIn", range)
        print("replacementString", string)
        //if latest input is from the characters not allowed is present (aka, empty), do not change the characters in the text range
        if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: inverted) != nil {
            return false
        } else if (textField.text?.contains("."))! && string.contains(".") {
            //if the text already contains a period and the string contains one as well, do not change output
            return false
        } else {
             //however, if not in the inverted set, allow the string to replace latest value in the text
            return true
        }
    }

}
```